# How to pass socket / file descriptor to other application in Android

Tags: android, sockets, ipc, file-descriptor

Is it possible to pass Socket/FileDescriptor from one activity to other activity in other application?
I tried using Intent but got

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File descriptors passed in Intent

Please help!

Comment: Sure you can using Binder service.<br>

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413810/sharing-file-descriptor-using-android-binder.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/23775778

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can - using content providers. Yo have to create your own content provider and override its method openFile. Read here, for instance: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/handling-binary-data-with-contentproviders/

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is: probably no, but...

Activity in the other application run in the other process. I believe, there is no ability to pass Socket or FileDescriptor from one process to another - neither in Java nor in Android. But it's possible in Linux using UNIX sockets and SCM_RIGHTS: man [unix(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html), [cmsg(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/cmsg.3.html). Since Android is based on Linux kernel, **probably** you can write this functionality in C and pass it to your Java code with JNI (see [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)). Possibly, you also have to implement your own versions of Socket and FileDescriptor. Summing up, I think you really don't want to do it all. Probably the best way - to review your task and find another, simpler solution.

Just in case: inside the one application you can reuse Sockets and FileDescriptors freely. For example, using static members and some kind of synchronization Intents.

Comment: This is blatantly incorrect. [A Java binding to SCM_RIGHTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html) has existed since earliest Android version. Android own IPC, Binder, [also had descriptor-passing functionality](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeFileDescriptor%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29) since earliest releases of platform.