# Sharing file descriptor using Android binder

Tags: android, android-binder

How can I share file descriptor across process using Android binder IPC in C++? Can you post example also?

Answer (score 7):

In client process we do the following to perform a binder transaction

```cpp
remote()->transact(MYTRANSACTION, data, &reply, IBinder::FLAG_ONEWAY);
```

data and reply are of type Parcel. marshall and unmarshalling is done in native android using Parcel objects. It has the functionality to marshall a file descriptor.

```cpp
data.writeFileDescriptor(fd);
```

In server process (i.e, Service in android), we call the following method
to read the file descriptor in the server process.

```cpp
int fd = data.readFileDescriptor();
```

sharing the file descriptor across process will be handled by the **binder driver**.

**Important** : duplicate the received file descriptor before the parcel object is destroyed.

You can find the implementation and explanation for native binder at
[Android-HelloWorldService](https://github.com/mcr/Android-HelloWorldService)

Comment: what do you mean by duplicating the received file descriptor before the parcel object is destroyed?

Comment: I got it. I always got illegal fd errors when doing mmap until I used the dup system call to duplicate the fd. Your "Note" statement is really important!!!